# Can a new mail be sent using AppleScript + Outlook + IMAP?

Tags: applescript, ms-office, imap

I'm trying to use apple script to automate creation of a new outlook mail message.

The below code will work when I have my email account sent up as pop3 but I need it to work with an IMAP account.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"test", plain text content:"", content:""}
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: What happens when you run this? How does your script choose POP or IMAP? (Or what are you doing to change outlook between runs of this same script?)

Comment: The script isn't selecting POP or IMAP its how the account is setup in outlook i.e. if i set an email account in outlook using POP3 the script work's and I get a new message in the drafts folder. Using IMAP the script runs with no errors but no new message appears. I get the same response in the results window "outgoing message id 108147 of application "Microsoft Outlook"" with both pop3 and imap